# WPF: Binding a List<class> to a ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I've been working on this problem for about 3 hours now, and I got to a dead end.
Currently I'm trying to bind a list to a ComboBox.

I have used several methods to bind the List:

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public coImportReader ir { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {          
        ir = new coImportReader();
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void PremadeSearchPoints(coSearchPoint sp)
    {
        //SearchRefPoint.DataContext = ir.SearchPointCollection;
        SearchRefPoint.ItemsSource = ir.SearchPointCollection;
        SearchRefPoint.DisplayMemberPath = Name;
```

The data was binded correctly but the DisplayMemeberPath for some reason returned the name of the class and not the name of it's member.

The XAML method returned an empty string...

```
<ComboBox x:Name="SearchRefPoint" Height="30" Width="324" Margin="0,10,0,0"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding ir.SearchPointCollection}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name">
```

I've also tried to fill it with a new list which I create in the MainWindow. the result was the same in both cases.

Also I've tried to create and ListCollectionView which was success, but the problem was that I could get the index of the ComboBox item. I prefer to work by an Id. For that reason I was looking for a new solution which I found at: http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2012/08/15/multi-columns-combo-box/

The problem with this example is that is not clear how the itemsource is being binded.

**Edit:**

To sum things up: I'm currently trying to bind a list(SearchPointsCollection) of objects(coSearchPoints) defined in a class (coImportReader).

```
namespace Import_Rates_Manager
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public coImportReader ir;
        public coViewerControles vc;
        public coSearchPoint sp;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ir = new coImportReader();
            vc = new coViewerControles();
            sp = new coSearchPoint();
            SearchRefPoint.DataContext = ir;
        }
   }
}

//in function.... 

SearchRefPoint.ItemsSource = ir.SearchPointCollection;
SearchRefPoint.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";

namespace Import_Rates_Manager
{
    public class coImportReader
    {      
        public List<coSearchPoint> SearchPointCollection = new List<coSearchPoint>();
    }
}

namespace Import_Rates_Manager
{
    public class coSearchPoint
    {
        public coSearchPoint()
        {
            string Name = "";
            Guid Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            IRange FoundCell = null;

        }
    }
}
```

This results in a filled combobox with no text

Comment: Any binding errors in the output?

Comment: No not really, it's in a try catch, and I'm not receiving any Exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a simple example using the MVVM Pattern

### XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Binding_a_List_to_a_ComboBox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left"
      VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding SearchPointCollection , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              SelectedIndex="{Binding MySelectedIndex, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" Grid.Row="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Otherstuff}" Grid.Row="2"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
    <Button Content="Bind NOW" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MySelectedIndex, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>

    <Grid  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
           DataContext="{Binding MySelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeValue}" Grid.Column="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

### Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using Import_Rates_Manager;

namespace Binding_a_List_to_a_ComboBox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataContext = new coImportReader();
        }    
    }
}
namespace Import_Rates_Manager
{
    public class coImportReader : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private List<coSearchPoint> myItemsSource;
        private int mySelectedIndex;
        private coSearchPoint mySelectedItem;

        public List<coSearchPoint> SearchPointCollection 
        {
            get { return myItemsSource; }
            set
            {
                myItemsSource = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SearchPointCollection ");
            }
        }

        public int MySelectedIndex
        {
            get { return mySelectedIndex; }
            set
            {
                mySelectedIndex = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MySelectedIndex");
            }
        }

        public coSearchPoint MySelectedItem
        {
            get { return mySelectedItem; }
            set { mySelectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MySelectedItem");
            }
        }

        #region cTor

        public coImportReader()
        {
            myItemsSource = new List<coSearchPoint>();
            myItemsSource.Add(new coSearchPoint { Name = "Name1" });
            myItemsSource.Add(new coSearchPoint { Name = "Name2" });
            myItemsSource.Add(new coSearchPoint { Name = "Name3" });
            myItemsSource.Add(new coSearchPoint { Name = "Name4" });
            myItemsSource.Add(new coSearchPoint { Name = "Name5" });
        }
        #endregion

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Member

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class coSearchPoint
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public IRange FoundCell { get; set; }    

        public coSearchPoint()
        {
            Name = "";
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            FoundCell = null;    
        }
    }

    public interface IRange
    {
        string SomeValue { get; }
    }
}
```

Here are 3 Classes:

- `MainWindow` which set VM as his Datacontext
- `coImportReader` the Class which  presents your properties for your bindings
- `coSearchPoint`  which is just a Container for your information
- `IRange`  which is just an Interface

Comment: Thanks you very much WiiMaxx, I will try this straight away :)

Comment: If you are an beginner in C# -> WPF you should read [WPF/MVVM Quick Start Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial)

Comment: @Nieksa does it solve your problem? if so please mark it as answer else specify your question or ask me if something unclear :-)

Comment: @Nieksa ok i will bind a working sample based on your shown code

Comment: Thanks alot WiiMaxx, i will try this out tonight. I give you the headsup later on.

Answer (score 1):

The Collection you are binding to needs to be a property of ir not a field.

Also try this :

```
public coImportReader ir { get; set; } 
public <type of SearchPointCollection> irCollection { get { return ir != null ? ir.SearchPointCollection : null; } }
```

Bind to irCollection and see what errors you get if any.

Answer (score 0):

The `DisplayMemberPath` should contain the property name of the elements in your collection. Assuming the elements in the `SearchPointCollection` are of the type `SearchPoint` and this class has a Property `SearchPointName` you should set `DisplayMemberPath` like this:

```
SearchRefPoint.DisplayMemberPath = "SearchPointName";
```

**Edit:**

In your code the class `coSearchPoint` has the Field `Name` defined in the Constructor. `Name` has to be a Property of the class, otherwise the Binding can't work.

Comment: Thank for the suggestion Roland. You are correct, it has the property SearchPointName, but unfortunately this returned an empty string as well.

Comment: @user2606038 can you give us the code of `coImportReader` and the class used in the collection (`SearchPoint`)?

Comment: Could it be that the datacontext off my ComboBox is set to the main window? If I define a new class (in the main window) to define the properties of the list, the combobox is filled with property SearchPointName. 

What if I put SearchPointName in a different class (Import_Rates_Manager) what would I have to set my ItemsSource or better, my DataContext to?